# Postgresql deadlock issue

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I have received the following deadlock error in pg_log:

```
2016-01-15 09:52:48.648 EST,"name","name",11694,"ip:40273",56988e35.2dae,1,"UPDATE",2016-01-15 01:14:13 EST,10/3886,49775,ERROR,40P01,
"deadlock detected",

"Process 11694 waits for ShareLock on transaction 49774; blocked by process 11685.

Process 11685 waits for ShareLock on transaction 49775; blocked by process 11694.

Process 11694: update bb_batter_season_stat set a_field=a_field+$1, ab_int=ab_int+$2, abvsl=abvsl+$3, abvsr=abvsr+$4, bbvsl=bbvsl+$5, bbvsr=bbvsr+$6, cs=cs+$7,
cs_field=cs_field+$8, ... where bb_players_id=$53

Process 11685: update bb_batter_season_stat set a_field=a_field+$1, ab_int=ab_int+$2, abvsl=abvsl+$3, abvsr=abvsr+$4, bbvsl=bbvsl+$5, bbvsr=bbvsr+$6, cs=cs+$7,
cs_field=cs_field+$8, ... where bb_players_id=$53","See server log for query details.",,,,

"update bb_batter_season_stat set a_field=a_field+$1, ab_int=ab_int+$2, abvsl=abvsl+$3,
abvsr=abvsr+$4, bbvsl=bbvsl+$5, bbvsr=bbvsr+$6, cs=cs+$7, cs_field=cs_field+$8, ... where bb_players_id=$53",,,""
```

I can't understand why is it happening. Two processes running same query and deadlock happens.

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE bb_batter_season_stat (
  id SERIAL  NOT NULL ,
  bb_players_id INTEGER   NOT NULL ,
  G SMALLINT    ,
  ABvsL SMALLINT    ,
  ABvsR SMALLINT    ,
  RvsL SMALLINT    ,
  RvsR SMALLINT    ,
  HvsL SMALLINT    ,
  HvsR SMALLINT    ,
  d2BvsL SMALLINT    ,
  d2BvsR SMALLINT    ,
  ...
PRIMARY KEY(id)  ,
  FOREIGN KEY(bb_players_id) REFERENCES bb_players(id) );

CREATE INDEX bb_batter_season_stat_FKIndex1 ON bb_batter_season_stat (bb_players_id);
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson same query same table. different processes doing update at the same time. yes both inside their own transactions. are you asking if there are another queries running on that table?

Comment: Find these updates in your code, and show us this code. Could be that there are two updates executed within one transaction, one updates `bb_batter_season_stat` table, the other one `bb_players`

Comment: Looks like these transactions have already updated some rows in `bb_batter_season_stat` before the deadlock happened. Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have at least 2 records in `bb_batter_season_stat` that have the same `bb_players_id`.

1. Transaction one locked for update the first record.
2. Transaction two locked the second.
3. Transaction one tried to lock the the second, but was blocked waiting for transaction two.
4. Transaction two tried to lock the first record, but was blocked waiting for transaction one, creating a deadlock.

To avoid this you should force locking of the records in the order of primary key. For example using `select for update`:

```
with ids as (
  select id
  from bb_batter_season_stat
  where bb_players_id=?
  order by id
  for update
)
update bb_batter_season_stat
  set a_field=a_field+$1, ab_int=ab_int+$2, …
  where id in (select id from ids);
```

Comment: interesting idea but i checked - there are no duplicate rows (by column bb_players_id)